# Launch different containers from a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there any possibility to launch containers of different images simultaneously from a single "Dockerfile" ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a misconception here. A `Dockerfile` is not responsible for launching a container. It's responsible for building an image (which you can then use `docker run ...` to create a container from). More info can be found on the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).

If you need to run many docker containers simultaneously I'd suggest you had a look at [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/) which you can use to run containers based on images either from the docker registry or custom-built via `Dockerfile`s

Answer (score 1):

Also somewhat new to Docker, but my understanding is that the Dockerfile is used to create Docker images, and then you start containers from images.

If you want to run multiple containers you need to use an orchestrator like docker swarm or Kubernetes.

Those have their own configuration files that tell it which images to spin up.